# How to create validator on form fields in model forms

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

How to validate model field title? What if for example, every use of the title field started with the word ‘Blog’.

```
models.py

class TitleAbstract(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Blog(TitleAbstract):
    ..............

forms.py

class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Blog

views.py

class BlogCreateView(CreateView):
     model = Blog
     action = 'created'
```

Comment: Have you read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**validators.py**

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_title(value):
    if not value.lower().startswith(u'blog'):
        msg = u"Enter a value starting with 'Blog'"
        raise ValidationError(msg)
```

**forms.py**

```
class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(BlogForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['title'].validators = [validate_title]

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
```

**views.py**

```
class BlogCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Blog
    action = 'created'
    form_class = BlogForm
```